# How to make a slider moves with jquery automatically every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, pagination, slider

Here the code I'm using:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/facemoi/DEpjM/3/)

HTML Part:

```
<div id="paginationdemo">                
<div id="p1" class="pagedemo _current" style="">
    <a href='#' class="link_title">
    <h3>Cu mei liber viderer mazim neglegentur</h3>
    <img src='http://s2.goodfon.com/wallpaper/previews/581412-n.jpg' width='450' height='250'>
        <p style="margin:2px; text-align:left; text-decoration:none">Cu mei liber viderer, mazim neglegentur eam ad. Quis scriptorem te usu, nonumes appetere eam in. Vix ridens consulatu an <a href='#' class="read_more"> (...Lire la suite)</a></p>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="p2" class="pagedemo" style="display:none;">
    <a href='#' class="link_title">
    <h3>Graecis persequeris ius no</h3>
    <img src='http://s2.goodfon.com/wallpaper/previews/414923-n.jpg' width='450' height='250'>
        <p style="margin:2px; text-align:left; text-decoration:none">Graecis persequeris ius no, fugit apeirian sea te. Quo iusto maiorum ad, ius te ancillae noluisse. Purto decore duo <a href='post.php' class="read_more"> (...Lire la suite)</a></p>
        </a>
</div>
....
<div id="paginationDiv"></div>
</div>
```

the slider moves only when I click on the pagination numbers.

How can i make it move and change topic every 5 seconds automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var lis = $(".jPag-pages li")
        console.log(lis.length)
        currentHighlight = 0;
        N = 5;//interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(currentHighlight)
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight+1 ) % lis.length;
        lis.eq(currentHighlight).click();
    }, N * 1000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DEpjM/6/)

Comment: And if i wanted the slider to continue looping. once it reaches currentHighlight == 14 and restart again from currentHighlight == 1 and so on..?